# How to use socks authentication in webdriverio

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io, firefox-profile

I would like to have SOCKSv5 authentication enabled in my webdriverio application. However it doesn't seem to work at the moment.

So far i have tried the following configurations:

1. Setting manually using **firefox-profile** as followed:

> ```
> fp.setProxy({ 
>     proxyType: 'manual', 
>     socksProxy: `127.0.0.1:1080`,
>     socksUsername: 'myuser',
>     socksPassword: 'mypass'
> });
> ```

this didn't seem to work as pages simply don't load.

2. Using **FoxyProxy**

I have tried setting the url using its api:

```
proxy:host=${proxy}&port=1080&isSocks=true&enabled=true&username=myuser&password=mypass
```

Which gave me a warning that something is accessing its configuration and thus declining the request.

Creating a custom firefox profile and then loading that one doesn't work as i will have to edit proxies during my applications runtime.

3. Updating selenium (3.3) and geckodriver (1.15) with the following configs

> ```
> requiredCapabilities: {
>     proxy:{
>         proxyType: 'manual',
>         socksProxy: '127.0.0.1',
>         socksProxyPort: 1080,
>         socksVersion: 5,
>         socksUsername: "mine",
>         socksPassword: "mine"
>     }
> }
> ```

or

```
desiredCapabilities: {
    proxy:{
        proxyType: 'manual',
        socksProxy: '127.0.0.1',
        socksProxyPort: 1080,
        socksVersion: 5,
        socksUsername: "mine",
        socksPassword: "mine"
    }
}
```

however neither seemed to be working, also tried passing the proxy as a JSON.stringify(proxyObj) instead of the direct object.

I run the entire stack as followed:

```
var options = { 
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox',
        proxy:{
            proxyType: 'manual',
            socksProxy: '127.0.0.1',
            socksProxyPort: 1080,
            socksVersion: 5,
            socksUsername: "mine",
            socksPassword: "mine"
        }
    }
};

var client = webdriverio.remote(options);
client
    .init()   
    .url('http://whatsmyip.org/')
    .end();
```

Has anybody came across a solution?

**log**

```
D:\Users\Maxim\Desktop\test>java -jar -Dwebdriver.geckodriver.driver="D:\Users\Maxim\Desktop\test\geckodriver.exe --log debug" selenium-server-standalone-3.3.0.jar
19:18:25.855 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.3.0', revision: 'b526bd5'
19:18:25.855 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
2017-03-13 19:18:25.875:INFO::main: Logging initialized @204ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
19:18:25.915 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
19:18:25.915 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver registration is skipped:
Unable to create new instances on this machine.
19:18:25.917 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
19:18:25.917 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
19:18:25.923 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver registration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=safari, version=, platform=MAC}] does not match the current platform WIN10
2017-03-13 19:18:25.961:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.20.v20161216
2017-03-13 19:18:25.988:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1bce4f0a{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2017-03-13 19:18:26.110:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@4bec1f0c{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4444}
2017-03-13 19:18:26.111:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @440ms
19:18:26.112 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
19:18:33.003 INFO - SessionCleaner initialized with insideBrowserTimeout 0 and clientGoneTimeout 1800000 polling every 180000
19:18:33.027 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{rotatable=true, proxy={socksUsername=mine, socksPassword=mine, socksVersion=5, proxyType=manual, socksProxyPort=1080, socksProxy=127.0.0.1}, locationContextEnabled=true, loggingPrefs=org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingPreferences@32b33674, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, requestOrigins={name=webdriverio, version=4.6.2, url=http://webdriver.io}}]])
19:18:33.035 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{rotatable=true, proxy={socksUsername=mine, socksPassword=mine, socksVersion=5, proxyType=manual, socksProxyPort=1080, socksProxy=127.0.0.1}, locationContextEnabled=true, loggingPrefs=org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingPreferences@32b33674, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, requestOrigins={name=webdriverio, version=4.6.2, url=http://webdriver.io}}]
1489429113379   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:2577
1489429113929   mozprofile::profile     INFO    Using profile path C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.RTu9x3vDqRxG
1489429113933   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program Files\Firefox Developer Edition\firefox.exe with args []
1489429113939   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:37915
[GPU 12472] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-aurora-w64-ntly-000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
1489429115925   Marionette      INFO    Listening on port 37915
19:18:36.041 WARN - Exception thrown
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '3.3.0', revision: 'b526bd5', time: '2017-03-07 11:21:31 -0800'
System info: host: 'MY-PC', ip: '10.0.75.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:183)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.<init>(DefaultSession.java:119)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.createSession(DefaultSession.java:95)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions.newSession(DefaultDriverSessions.java:131)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:59)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:36)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:111)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpCommandHandler.handleRequest(JsonHttpCommandHandler.java:190)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverServlet.java:222)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:184)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.service(DriverServlet.java:150)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:543)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1228)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:481)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1130)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:112)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '3.3.0', revision: 'b526bd5', time: '2017-03-07 11:21:31 -0800'
System info: host: 'MY-PC', ip: '10.0.75.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.callConstructor(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:89)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.newInstance(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:63)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:60)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:222)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:209)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.callConstructor(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:81)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{rotatable=true, proxy={"proxyAutoconfigUrl":null,"autodetect":false,"socksPassword":"mine","socksUsername":"mine","httpProxy":null,"proxyType":"MANUAL","noProxy":null,"ftpProxy":null,"socksProxy":"127.0.0.1","hCode":1194763275,"class":"org.openqa.selenium.Proxy","sslProxy":null}, locationContextEnabled=true, loggingPrefs=org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingPreferences@32b33674, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, moz:firefoxOptions={binary=Optional.empty, args=[], legacy=null, logLevel=null, prefs={}, profile=null}, requestOrigins={name=webdriverio, version=4.6.2, url=http://webdriver.io}}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: '3.3.0', revision: 'b526bd5', time: '2017-03-07 11:21:31 -0800'
System info: host: 'MY-PC', ip: '10.0.75.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:244)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:243)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:121)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:164)
        ... 14 more
19:18:36.048 WARN - Exception: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{rotatable=true, proxy={"proxyAutoconfigUrl":null,"autodetect":false,"socksPassword":"mine","socksUsername":"mine","httpProxy":null,"proxyType":"MANUAL","noProxy":null,"ftpProxy":null,"socksProxy":"127.0.0.1","hCode":1194763275,"class":"org.openqa.selenium.Proxy","sslProxy":null}, locationContextEnabled=true, loggingPrefs=org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingPreferences@32b33674, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, moz:firefoxOptions={binary=Optional.empty, args=[], legacy=null, logLevel=null, prefs={}, profile=null}, requestOrigins={name=webdriverio, version=4.6.2, url=http://webdriver.io}}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: '3.3.0', revision: 'b526bd5', time: '2017-03-07 11:21:31 -0800'
System info: host: 'MY-PC', ip: '10.0.75.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
```

Comment: you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are aware of this but the mozilla team has recently decided to implement their own browser automation tool called marionette. They have also implemented a proxy (called geckodriver) to sit between a webdriver-compatible client and marionette. These tools are still under very active development and as a result some parts of them might not work as expected. You should take a look at [this bug report](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/97) for how to properly set a proxy using the required capabilities option.

I had faced the same issue earlier and I had to go and patch geckodriver myself. Since then things seem to have improved, but since I am not 100% sure of the changes and I was using python and the python bindings I am not sure how to use required capabilities with webdriverio and nodejs.

Could you try the following config:

```
var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        requiredCapabilities: {
        proxy:{
            proxyType: 'manual',
            socksProxy: '127.0.0.1',
            socksProxyPort: 1080,
            socksVersion: 5,
            socksUsername: "mine",
            socksPassword: "mine"
        }
    }
}
```

If i am not mistaken geckodriver searches for requiredCapabilities inside capabilities. That's what the [w3c specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#processing-capabilities) of the webdriver protocol also suggests.

At this point based on your answers, I think the problem is actually authenticating at the proxy. I looked around at the source code for marionette and although they have some unit tests for testing socks proxies those tests don't check if the username/password are set. As a result I am not sure whether it works properly.

My suggestion would be to check whether you could handle this on the proxy side. For example if the proxy handles ip-based authentication, you could set that up and only allow traffic from your ip.

You could always look into using another browser instead of firefox.

Comment: Tried: Changing desiredCapabilities with requiredCapabilities, passing proxy as a string instead of a proxy object. in both, version 47 and 52 with latest geckodriver (1.15) and selenium (3.3). Tried mixing these combinations but neither got the socksProxy working (added original answer)

Comment: @MaximGeerinck, hmm could you add a snippet on how you start up the driver with capabilities and required capabilities?  Also can you try again while setting geckodriver with the -vv flag to get a verbose log and add the log to your question?

Comment: I have added extra information on how i start the program, including log details. Some important errors occur but im unable to fix those

Comment: @MaximGeerinck I edited my answer. Could you try this config?

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late response. The Browser now starts, however the proxy doesn't seem to be working (im guessing it doesn't use authentication but not sure). No log errors pop up

Comment: @MaximGeerinck with the browser open, got to Preferences -> Advanced -> Network -> Settings  and tell me what it says at SOCKS host. Also check your socks proxy is working properly. Have you tried connecting to the proxy through a normal firefox session

Comment: I have tried filling it in manually before, however it never asks me for my username and password. When using addons such as foxyproxy or a tool like proxifier, it works fine.

Comment: @MaximGeerinck I updated my answer with some suggestions

Comment: Thank you for the addition. However, I have already investigated that part and it won't be suitable solution in my case.